# Object with null values are created

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

After creating object of class Details, when i upload it to firebase it creates a child having null values, also object contains one parameter less ie image. name = "" cost = "" location = "" genre = "" phone = "" image = "" missing

Code:

```
package com.example.amitroshan.dairyvilla;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.text.format.DateUtils;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseListAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.util.Random;

public class Feed extends Fragment {

    DatabaseReference mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Books");
    static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;

    private EditText upload_name, upload_location, upload_cost, upload_genre, upload_phone;
    private Button send;
    private ImageButton upload;
    private String upload_url;

    public Feed() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            upload.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);
            //Uri filePath = data.getData();

            FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://dairyvilla-3623a.appspot.com/");
            StorageReference mountainImagesRef = storageRef.child("images/" + new Random(10000) + ".jpg");
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 20, baos);
            byte[] mdata = baos.toByteArray();
            UploadTask uploadTask = mountainImagesRef.putBytes(mdata);
            uploadTask.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                    upload_url = task.getResult().getDownloadUrl().toString();
                    //pro.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_feed, container, false);

        upload_name = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_name);
        upload_location = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_location);
        upload_cost = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_cost);
        upload_genre = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_genre);
        upload_phone = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_phone);
        upload = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
        send = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.upload_button);


        upload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            }
        });

        final Details d = new Details(upload_name.getText().toString(),upload_location.getText().toString(),
                upload_cost.getText().toString(),upload_genre.getText().toString(),
                upload_url,upload_phone.getText().toString());

        send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mRef.child(mRef.push().getKey()).setValue(d);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Uploading Complete..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


        return v;
    }

}

class Details{

    String name, location, cost, genre, phone, image;

    public Details(String name, String location, String cost, String genre, String image, String phone) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.genre = genre;
        this.image = image;
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getPhone() {
        return phone;
    }

    public void setPhone(String phone) {
        this.phone = phone;
    }

    public String getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    public void setImage(String image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public String getGenre() {
        return genre;
    }

    public void setGenre(String genre) {
        this.genre = genre;
    }

    public String getCost() {
        return cost;
    }

    public void setCost(String cost) {
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to push objects into firebase your data model class needs an empty constructor.

In this case

```
public Details() {}
```

And instead of this

```
mRef.child(mRef.push().getKey()).setValue(d);
```

just use this

```
mRef.push().setValue(d);
```

Update:

You create your object with all variables in your onCreateView-Method. At this time the Text Views are all empty, thus they return an empty String.
Try to move

```
final Details d = new Details(upload_name.getText().toString(),upload_location.getText().toString(),
            upload_cost.getText().toString(),upload_genre.getText().toString(),
            upload_url,upload_phone.getText().toString());
```

inside the click listener.

Answer (score 1):

For pushing objects in Firebase database you will need to create an empty constructor in the class and than push all the values using this:

```
clientName.push().setValue(n);
```

Comment: creating an empty constructor is not helping